# Is it permissible to make money from writing Torah books?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, money, chinuch-education

I  know that Torah needs to be taught for free ([Hilchos Talmud Torah 1.2](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh5/6/1/2.htm)):

> ...אסור ללמד תורה בשכר שנאמר ואותי צוה ה' בעת ההיא ללמד אתכם חוקים ומשפטים מה אני בחנם אף אתם בחנם...‏

And, if not required, it is preferable not to make money from one's Torah learning even if, when learning, one did not have the money in mind ([ibid 4.14](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh5/6/4/14.htm)):

> ...כל הנהנה מדברי תורה נוטל חייו מן העולם...‏

And [ibid 4.16](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh5/6/4/16.htm):

> אך מי שחננו ה' שיוכל להתפרנס ממעשה ידיו שיעשה עראי לבד ותורתו קבע אסור לו להתפרנס מהתורה אף על פי שמניח מלאכתו ומעשה ידיו בשביל זה שהוא שכר בטלה דמוכח.
>   ואפילו מתמנה להורות הוראות שיש לו פנאי הרבה ללמוד ויוכל לבא לידי ידיעת התורה כולה מאחר שאם היה מתפרנס ממעשה ידיו והיה עושה תורתו קבע היה מקיים מצות ודברת בם ואף שלא היה יכול לבא לידי ידיעת התורה כולה במשך זמן כזה שיוכל לבא עכשיו הרי אמרו לא עליך המלאכה לגמור ולכך אין עליו להשתמש בכתר תורה בשביל כך.
>   אלא אם כן רבים צריכים לו שאין במדינה גדול בחכמה כמוהו והוא בורח מן הגדולה והגדולה מחזרת אחריו שאז עון בידו להמנע וחייב הוא להתמנות.‏

Is making money from a book an exception (i.e. that one is allowed to make the money for the work he did in writing it), even when it is not necessary (e.g. he has enough money for sustenance already) or is it like teaching?

What if you are not the writer but the publisher, can you pay the writer (if he needs it) and then make profit from selling the writer's books?

Comment: אפילו אינו בעל מלאכה ואומנות כלל לפי שאלו לא למד עמהם בודאי היה מוכרח לעשות איזה עסק להחיות נפשו ונפשות ביתו ועכשיו שלומד עמהם כל היום ואינו עוסק כלל אין לך שכר בטילה הניכר ומוכח גדול מזה

Comment: @ShmuelBrin my question is sposificly about אך מי שחננו ה' שיוכל להתפרנס ממעשה ידיו שיעשה עראי לבד ותורתו קבע אסור לו להתפרנס מהתורה אף על פי שמניח מלאכתו ומעשה ידיו בשביל זה שהוא שכר בטלה דמוכח.

Answer (score 1):

Rav `Ovadyah Yosef A"H received payment for books he published (as mentioned in [*Maran*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1600913407) among other places). It's this money he received that allowed him to continue learning and publishing.

Comment: +1 So you are saying it is like teaching that if you can support yourself:(from other sources) you should not charge for it

Comment: Perhaps that follows logically; but, all I meant to convey is a *Ma\`aseh Rav* from Rav \`Ovadyah Yosef A"H (himself a staunch supporter of HaRaMBa"M).

Comment: But R. Karo, whom rabbi yosef was an even bigger follower of, fiercely disputes this ruling of Rambam.

Comment: @mevaqesh Nevertheless, the *Ma\`aseh Rav* from Rav \`Ovadyah stands. It is also true that there are cases in which Rav \`Ovadyah did not rule *lema\`aseh* in absolute accordance with Hashulhan \`Arukh (e.g. when an existing custom was well-founded and well-established).

Comment: @Lee this answer is still basically irrelevant. I could just as easily quote the kessef Mishneh who disputes the whole thing, as presumably does rabbi yossef, who probably thought that kollel study isn't forbidden.

Comment: @mevaqesh You could and should do that (with a source cited). I cited a *Ma\`aseh Rav*. I find citing a *Ma\`aseh Rav* quite relevant.